# Inject JS in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I am try to  inject the below JS in web view:

```
    var disqusData = { 
        id: '123456',
        username: 'hello1234',
        email: 'exampe@example.com'
    };



    loadComments("phillydotcom", "http://www.philly.com/philly/news/20140414_From_hell_to_heaven__Problem_property_to_be_razed_for_luxury_apartments.html", "From%20hell%20to%20heaven:%20Problem%20property%20razed%20for%20luxury%20apartments", "255112141" )
```

I used the below code but it only show blank page

```
    webDisqus = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.disqus);
// set up disqus
WebSettings webSettings2 = webDisqus.getSettings();
webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings2.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webDisqus.requestFocusFromTouch();
   webDisqus.loadUrl("javascript:var disqusData = { "+
                "id: '123456',"+
                "username: 'hello1234',"+
                "email: 'example@example.com'"+
                "};"+
                "loadComments(\"phillydotcom\", \"http://www.philly.com/philly/news/20140414_From_hell_to_heaven" +
                "__Problem_property_to_be_razed_for_luxury_apartments.html\"," +
                " \"From%20hell%20to%20heaven:%20Problem%20property%20razed%20for%20luxury%20apartments\", \"255112141\" )");
```

Comment: How do you configure your WebView? Is JavaScript enabled? Please share more code. Do you see any errors in logcat? Where is the loadComments() function defined?

Comment: I have added extra code, yes I have enabled javascript. When I tried to lodurl(url) works fine, but the JS script is not working. In IOS they have something like evaluate and this script works fine in ios.

Comment: Where is the loadComments function defined?